# Random value from Dictionary?

Tags: c#, random, dictionary

```
var dd = new Dictionary<Guid, object>(); //readonly in my real code
dd.Add( Guid.NewGuid() , 'a');
dd.Add( Guid.NewGuid() , 'a');
dd.Add( Guid.NewGuid() , 'a');
var randone = dd.ElementAt(new Random(dd.Count()).Next(dd.Count));
```

I want to get a random value from dd as fast as possible (every ms counts), but I am pretty sure I am not doing that with the above sample. How can randone be redone to get a random KeyValuePair? In the actual code, the key is in fact a GUID but the value is a custom POCO.

Comment: Seeding `Random` with the count of items will lead you do a decidedly *not* random result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can keep all the keys in a `List<T>` then you can just choose a random number between 0 and List.Count. Index into the list using that number (simple lookup) and then use that to index into your dictionary.

Comment: My actual code has many Dictionaries, each with thousands of k/v pairs, so wouldn't duplicating all keys in a list add extra overhead?

Comment: It's a tradeoff, memory for speed. It would add extra overhead in terms of taking up more memory, but if speed is your number one concern, then this is your best option. I would argue that the amount of memory overhead that this might add is probably very minimal anyway.